# $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{\sin2x}-e^{\sin x}}{x}$ without L'Hospital

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Anyone has an idea how to find $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{e^{\sin2x}-e^{\sin x}}{x}$ without L'Hospital? I solved it with L'Hospital and the result is $1$ but the assignment is to find it without L'Hospital. Any idea?

Comment: Taylor expansion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have more elementary way.
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{\sin 2x}-e^{\sin x}}{x}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{2\sin x\cos x}-e^{\sin x}}{x}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{\sin x}(e^{2\sin x\cos x - \sin x}-1)}{x}=$$
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{e^{\sin x(2\cos x -1)}-1}{\sin x(2\cos x -1)}\cdot \frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot e^{\sin x}(2\cos x-1)=1\cdot1\cdot1\cdot(2-1)=1 $$
Using the limit: 
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$$

Comment: It seems to me that you are implicitly using L'Hospital to simplify $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}$.  So I am not sure how this is "more elementary."

Comment: One can prove that $\sin x / x \to 1$ using a geometric argument, @Ryan. It's usually used to find the formula for the derivative of $\sin$.

Comment: @Ryan We are allowed in class to use some basic "known" limits when finding limits without explicitly computing them. And also when we learned about function sin, we had limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}$ as part of our definition of this function(we defined elementary function, and proved the existence later). The taylor series is yet to be introduced to us in our course, so that is why I called it more elementary. I guess the way you see it depends on syllabus of your course.

Comment: @Ryan: the fact that $\sin x/x \to 1$ as $ x \to 0$ can be proved in variety of ways but it can't be proved using L'Hospital's Rule. Note that to apply L'Hospital on $\sin x/x$ you need to know the derivative of $\sin x$. The fact that derivative of $\sin x$ is $\cos x$ depends on the limit of $\sin x/x$. Hence application of LHR for $\sin x/x$ is circular. By the way this seems to be the best answer for this question. +1 to D.N

Answer (score 12):

**Hint:** Let $f(x)=e^{\sin(2x)}-e^{\sin(x)}$, for all $x\in \mathbb R$.

Note that $f(0)=0$ and think about the definition of $f'(0)$.

Comment: Isn't this the same as L'Hopital, if I'm thinking correctly?

Comment: @SanathDevalapurkar How so?

Comment: Ah, I wasn't thinking correctly. My mistake! (+1)

Comment: Comment, down voter?

Answer (score 4):

Note that

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{\sin 2x} - e^{\sin x}}{x} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{\sin 2x} - e^{\sin x}}{\sin x}$$

after using the fact that $\sin x / x \to 1$ as $x \to 0$. Now from the identity $\sin 2x = 2 \sin x \cos x$, and making the substitution $t = \sin x$, we want to compute

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{e^{2t \sqrt{1 - t^2}} - e^t}{t}$$

Now  by a Taylor expansion, the numerator is

$$2t \sqrt{1 - t^2} - t + o(t^2)$$

Dividing by $t$ now means that we want to compute

$$\lim_{t \to 0} 2 \sqrt{1 - t^2} - 1 = 1$$

Answer (score 4):

$e^{sin2x} \sim_0 sin2x + 1$, and also $e^{sinx} \sim_0 sinx + 1$. Thus:

$\dfrac{e^{sin2x} - e^{sinx}}{x} \sim_0 \dfrac{sin2x + 1 - sinx - 1}{x} \sim_0 \dfrac{2x - x}{x} = \dfrac{x}{x} = 1$

Comment: +1, this is exactly the way I would have solved it. Very succinct.

Comment: I think it is not strict to write $e^{\sin {2x}}-e^{\sin {x}}$ ~ $\sin 2x-\sin x$.  Actually,  we can only use it without extra proof on multiplication. $$$$Suggetion: Using Tyler's series can be more acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

$$\eqalign{
\lim_{x \to 0} \dfrac{e^{\sin2x}-e^{\sin x}}{x}
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\dfrac{1}{x}+\dfrac{\sin2x}{x}+\dfrac{\sin^22x}{2x}+\cdots-\dfrac{1}{x}-\dfrac{\sin x}{x}-\dfrac{\sin^2 x}{2x}-\cdots\right)\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\dfrac{\sin2x}{x}+\dfrac{\sin^22x}{2x}+\cdots-\dfrac{\sin x}{x}-\dfrac{\sin^2 x}{2x}-\cdots\right)\\
&=\left(2+0+\cdots-1-0-\cdots\right)\\
&=2-1=1}$$